# Which one must I use, MyDbContext.Blogs.Add(ablog) or MyDbContext.Add(ablog)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-2.0

Consider I have a context `MyDbContext` inherits `DbContext` of EFCore 2.0.
`Blogs` is a `DbSet<Blog>` and `Blog` is an entity model.

When I add a new `Blog` instance, `ablog` to the `Blogs`, which one must I use?

`MyDbContext.Add(ablog);` or `MyDbContext.Blogs.Add(ablog);`?

How about `Find`?

`MyDbContext.Find<Blog>(1);` or `MyDbContext.Blogs.Find(1);`?

Is there any benefit to use one over the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding directly data via the `DbContext`  is new to the `DbContext` in Entity Framework Core and have no equivalents in previous version of Entity Framework where the `DbContext` is available (i.e. EF 4.1 onwards).

But there is no difference [because](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data):

> When you use either version of `Add` the `context` begins tracking the
>   entity that was passed in to the method and applies an `EntityState`
>   value of Added to it. The context also applies the same `EntityState`
>   value of Added to all other objects in the graph that aren't already
>   being tracked by the `context`.

Also there is a generic version of `Add` ([`Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)`](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data)) but as Visual Studio also suggests you can omit the type parameter  because the compiler will infer the type from the argument passed in to the method.